# How to restructure javascript functions to output data in different function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if you can help me. I have some code that works that I have been trying to restructure. This is how it looks now:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportID, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0))
  });
}

function reportHandler(id, r2, retries){
    if(retries >= 3){
        console.log("Retried 3 times - stopping")
        return
    }
    if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
        console.log("Not ready");
        setTimeout(function() {
          getReport(id, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(id, r2, retries + 1))
        }, 2000);
      }
      console.log(r2);
}

function getReport(ref, type, granularity, from, to, metric, element) {
  return $.getJSON("report.php", {
    ref: ref,
    type: type,
    granularity: granularity,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    metric: metric,
    element: element,
  });
}
```

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to process the data, which I want to be able to do in myfunction.

At the moment the only way I can do is return the data in my report handler function.

I want to be able to return the data from the API in my myfunction function where I will then process it further, and then keep my reporthander and getreport functions generic.

Comment: Use `then` instead of `done` to pipe outputs.

Comment: @plalx It's a good idea but seems I'm not using the propert syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem resides here:

```
getReport(r1.reportID, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0))
```

`$.getJSON()` functions as a promise, with `.done()` being identical in functionality to `.then()`. Both of these accept a function as an argument, but the way you're passing it is not proper syntax. By passing the function with parameters instead of just its name, you're telling JavaScript to run the function and use its results - which isn't what you want. In your case, the simplest fix will be:

```
getReport(r1.reportId, "get").done((r2) => { reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0); });
```

Alternately, if you're able to use the new async/await syntax, you could make it simpler:

```
const r2 = await getReport(r1.reportId, "get");
const handler = await reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0);
// and so on
```

Does this make sense? Please let us know if there's anything else you don't understand.

EDIT: Okay, so per the comments on this answer, the code being run is correctly structured as:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportId, "get").done((r2) => {
      reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0);
    });
  });
}
```

The only answer I can think, then, is that the first `getReport()` call within `myFunction()` is not returning an object with `reportId` in the body. Are you getting any uncaught errors when this code runs?

EDIT 2: Per comments, the attribute was being incorrectly referenced due to a capitalization error. The code was calling for `r1.reportId` when the response was returning `r1.reportID`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I'm trying to put it together and it looks like this: ```function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
  getReport(r1.reportId, "get").done((r2) => { reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0); });
  });
}``` but it doesnt seem to pass the report ID across

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `getReport()` function is returning the right results? You can do this by putting `console.log(r1);` in the callback, ahead of your second `getReport()` call. Namely, I'm wondering whether the first call is returning an object with a `reportId` attribute.

Comment: Yes that seems to be fine - just the report ID doesn't appear in the url request with 'get' with your line

Comment: I just want to confirm, should I just be switching out that one line with your code and it should work?

Comment: What you have written in the comments is correct. Your original post is missing the curly brackets around `reportHandler()`, so I wasn't sure if you had those in your original code or not. Check your code to make sure they're there. Editing my answer here in a second.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I get the same error. When it runs the get query it doesn't include the reportID. I've put the full code and effort here: https://gist.github.com/hiven/cbba207596d4b44196767745fbfa1fa8

Comment: Actually, I think I've found the issue one second

Comment: It had to have a capital D in reportID that was the only issue

Comment: Awesome! Glad you were able to find it! It's often the simplest problems that are the most vexing.